# A HttpClient that blocks when a maximum number of requests are being processed?

Tags: java, concurrency

I'm using a HttpClient singleton across my entire application, at any given time it must at most handle 3 requests concurrently. I want to block any thread that tries to execute a request when 3 requests are being processed. Here is my code so far:

```
public class BlockingHttpClient implements HttpClient {

    private static final int MAX_CONNECTIONS = 3;

    private static BlockingHttpClient instance;
    private HttpClient delegate;
    private Semaphore semaphore;

    private BlockingHttpClient() {
        delegate = new DefaultHttpClient();
        semaphore = new Semaphore(MAX_CONNECTIONS, true);
        // Set delegate with a thread-safe connectionmanager and params etc..
    }

    public static synchronized BlockingHttpClient getInstance() {
        if(instance == null) {
            instance = new BlockingHttpClient();
        }

        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public HttpResponse execute(HttpUriRequest request) throws IOException,
            ClientProtocolException {
        HttpResponse response = null;

        try {
            semaphore.acquire();
            response = delegate.execute(request);
            semaphore.release();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;
    }

     .... the other delegated methods look the same ...
```

What I'm worried about is that this is ugly, i.e. if the calling thread get's interrupted while acquring then the returned response will be null. I'm also pretty green when it comes to concurrency in Java, are there any other problems with this approach?

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid returning a null response, one dirty trick you could use would be:

```
    boolean responseOK;
    do {
        try {
            semaphore.acquire();
            response = delegate.execute(request);
            semaphore.release();
            responseOK = true;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            responseOK = false;
        }
    } while(!responseOK);
```

I know is kind of dirty, and maybe you could add some sleeping between iterations to prevent it from turning into an active wait, but it's a way to ensure the request will eventually be executed (if the other requests finish, that is...).

Hope it helps!

Comment: yes, it wastes CPU time. One quick solution is sleeping the thread for 100 milliseconds everytime the InterruptedException is caught (i.e. Thread.sleep(100))

Comment: Busy-waiting on an Android device probably isn't the best idea, nevertheless this is a solution.